# Why are we only allowed to remove a function from the limit if the function is continuous in it's domain?

Tags: calculus

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsw0g.png)

Why we are only allowed to remove sin and cos from the limit expression if they're continuous in their domain? What if I had a removable discontinuity or something why would I not be able to remove the functions from the limit expression?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the pic it says "Because sinx and cosx are continuous over their whole domains, we can remove them from the limit expression." if I had two functions that weren't continuous over their whole domains why would I not be able to remove them from the limit expression.

Comment: You do not need continuity; as long as they are defined (as is the case here) you can "remove them" (more properly, you can factor them out of the limit). The limit is with respect to $h$ and those terms can be considered to be constants.

Comment: "familiar and easy-to-evaluate trigonometric limits"?? This appears to be a derivation of the derivative of $\sin x$. At the time one first encounter this, those trigonometric limits are neither familiar nor easy to evaluate! They usually must be proven using somewhat vague geometric comparisons. In particular that the area of a subset is less than or equal to the area of the superset, before a precise definition of "area" that could justify this inequality has been developed.